# c# one conn object with either mysql or sqlserver

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I've searched for this but not sure what to look for.

I'm working on an application that can connect to either SqlServer or MySQL.  I'd like to do it with one process function that uses either the MySqlConnection or the SQLConnection object (as well as the MysqlReader and SqlReader objects).

Is there a way I can set a connection object to one or the other, depending on which I'm using?

It doesn't need to connect to both in the same execution.

Right now I'm using a processQuery() and a processQueryMysql(), but I'd like to combine them into one.

I'd also like to avoid doing this:

```
SqlConnection connsql;
MysqlConnection connmysql;
if (mysql) {
    connmysql = new mysqlconnection();
    connmysql.Open();
} else {
    connsql = new sqlconnection();
    open connsql();
}
```

I'd prefer to just do :

eithersqltype conn

```
if (mysql)
    conn = new MysqlConnection()
else
    conn = new SqlConnection()

conn.Open();
```

and then use conn as normal (except where the mysql function calls are different, obviously)

Is there an elegant way to do something like this or am I better off another way?

Comment: What would you define your conn object as? It can't be both a sql connection and a mysql connection. An object has a type and it isn't some sort of variant.

Comment: Hint: Look for any common base classes or interfaces that both `MysqlConnection` and `SqlConnection` share (Such as `DbConnection` or `IDbConnection`)

Comment: If you want to have one common object you could always create your own interface and hide the required implementation behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define conn with IDbConnection interface

IDbConnection conn;

Read the article about IDbConnection interface below:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks sir.  That's what I needed!